# After zip deloy, azure app service dont have any function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created C# Azure Timmer function, then I published the App using GUI publish on Visual Studio, everything worked. Then I change to use Powershell script:

```
$username = $creds.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $creds.Properties.PublishingPassword
$apiUrl = "https://" + $FuncAppName + ".scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$filePath = "publish.zip"
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Don't get any error, but when I check on Azure, my Service app doesn't have my new function. So how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're not getting any errors? Are username and password OK? What shows up in the Deployments blade for the app service? Is the app name correct? So many questions, so little information... Please refer to [ask].

Comment: @rickvdbosch: I type the above commands and press enter, no errors appear, so I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Are sure your filepath is a full path or just a sample here?If you omit the path, the default is the current location.

Comment: @GeorgeChen I tried both Full and Omit path

Answer (score 1):

The `apiUrl` should point to the `wwwroot` folder, for `zipDeploy`

```
$apiUrl = "https://" + $functionAppName + ".scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot"
```

This is what i've been using and it works fine.

Comment: got this: No route registered for '/api/zip/site/wwwroot'